# Angular, which event can be fired before browser refresh

Tags: angularjs, refresh

`stateChangeStart` is not fired when refresh page.

```
        this.scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', (event, next, current) => {
            if(!confirm("Are you sure you want to refresh this page?")) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
```

`stateChangeSuccess` is only fired when the page refresh is already done.

which event would be fired before the refresh?

---

UPDATE:
tried `window.onbeforeunload` not working in my case
this is part of my code, is that right?

```
export default class TableController {
    constructor($scope,$state, $location) {
        //some initialization here
        window.onbeforeunload = function() {
            console.log('onbeforeunload');
            debugger;
            return null;
        }
    }
    //other coll functions
    ...
}
```

Comment: statechangestart happens on root scope like this..$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(e, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    if (toState.module === 'private' && !$cookies.Session) {

Answer (score 0):

Handling the page refresh is not part of angular state's job.

Use `window.onbeforeunload`.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
   return "are your sure?";
}
```

NOTE: 
This function bound to `window.onbeforeunload` will not be removed when angular's state changes. you need to manually set it to null when you don't need it any more.

```
window.onbeforeunload = undefined
```

Comment: updated my question, is it right to put the function inside constructor? currently it does not fire if I refresh. thanks

Answer (score 0):

State change events are done at root scope. Probably that might be the reason as it is not working. Please refer the documentation on how to call the state change events.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events